# Sum of values in tensor slice in python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm working in python/tensorflow. I have a tensor x (4 dimensions) and want to take the sum over a slice of the tensor

```
np.sum(x[:,:,:,0])
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code works fine for me when I generate the np array using x = `np.random.random_sample((5,3,2,2))`  and other numbers. What does `x` look like?

Comment: The tensor x is the output of a convolutional neural network.

Comment: Tell us about `x`, `shape` and `dtype`.

Comment: x = {Tensor} Tensor("concatenate_16/concat:0", shape=(?,?,?,64),dtype=float32) The ? are because the resolution of the images is different for all the images in the dataset I am using. I need this summation operation in the evaluation of the loss function during training.

Comment: When I write K.sum(x[:,:,:,0]), I get a tensor of shape () and dtype float32, probably this will have the correct value. But I want a number instead of a tensor because I want to do calculations with it...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using TF 1.x, you can't do simple numpy operations on TF tensors (in TF 1.x). Instead do the following.

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.random_normal(shape=[10, 5, 3, 2])
res = tf.reduce_sum(tf.gather(x, 0, axis=-1))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  r = sess.run(res)
```